# If I change an ODBC DSN from the registry in Windows 7, will my linked tables in MS Access need refreshed?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ms-access, database-migration, visual-foxpro

If I update the ODBC DSN registry entries to reflect server migration changes, will the linked tables that use these in local MS-Access databases need refreshed, or will they just automatically point to the linked tables on the other server?  Or does it depend on the driver?

This will apply to both 32-bit and 64-bit systems using ODBC drivers for Visual Fox Pro (free table directories), MySQL, and SQL Server.

Here are the registry paths in question as I understand them:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\ODBC\ODBC.INI`
**Registry path for 32-bit ODBC DSNs on a 32-bit system, or 64-bit ODBC DSNs on a 64-bit system.**

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ODBC\ODBC.INI`
**Registry path for 32-bit ODBC DSNs on a 64-bit system.**

Comment: Why not just change the registry entries and reopen Microsoft access and see what happens? If you want to be double sure, open up the database in access with procmon running, and see if it reads the DNS registry keys.

Answer (score 0):

Your linked tables won't see the change. You have to use "Linked Table Manager" to refresh connection data.

See: http://www.addintools.com/documents/access/where-is-linked-table-manager.html

and: http://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/modifying-linked-tables.html

Comment: Anotherwords, the tables linked tables need to be refreshed.